# susy not working with compass + sass on osx

Tags: macos, sass, susy-compass

I have everything installing, pre version of compass, latest version of sass and latest version of susy (pre) this is my gem list.

```
bigdecimal (1.2.0) 
bower (0.0.2) 
CFPropertyList (2.2.0) 
chunky_png (1.3.0, 1.2.9) 
compass (1.0.0.alpha.19, 0.12.6) 
compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.19) 
compass-import-once (1.0.4) 
ffi (1.9.3) 
foundation (1.0.4) 
fssm (0.2.10) 
io-console (0.4.2) 
json (1.7.7) 
libxml-ruby (2.6.0) 
listen (1.1.6) 
minitest (4.3.2) 
multi_json (1.10.0) 
nokogiri (1.5.6) 
psych (2.0.0) 
rake (0.9.6) 
rb-fsevent (0.9.4) 
rb-inotify (0.9.4) 
rb-kqueue (0.2.2) 
rdoc (4.0.0) 
rubygems-update (2.2.2) 
sass (3.3.7) 
sqlite3 (1.3.7) 
susy (2.1.2) 
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
```

So I have everything installed in theory, I made a new compass project and everything went smooth, but when editing the config.rb file using require susy, this is the message:

```
NoMethodError on line ["267"] of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.19/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb: susy
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Any idea why this is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Codekit 2, susy 2 is built in and you don't need to specify it in your config.rb.